# Magento 2 - custom attribute for Shipping method / Carrier

Tags: magento2

I would like to add custom attribute for shipping method so that I can set it up in admin panel:

[image]

I know it should be done in Setup\InstallSchema.php, but what entity name shall I use instead of `Product::Entity`?

```
// Add our "features" attribute
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, 'features', [
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Features',
        'input' => 'textarea',
        'required' => false,
        'sort_order' => 100,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set it up in `etc/adminhtml/system.xml`:

```
<system>
    <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <group id="gls" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">


            <field id="YOUR CUSTOM FIELD ID" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Label</label>
            </field> 


        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```